# Automate the google chrome update through scripting for every logon using powershell.

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

Title: Automate the google chrome update through scripting for every logon using powershell.

Anyone wants to take a shot at writing the code? If not maybe guide me towards it. I have little experience.

I need google chrome to update the moment the user logs on through a script that I can push to multiple computers at the same time.

Thanks in advance! -Albert

Comment: I already told you that there aren't any script writing service sites here when you asked this question on serverfault.

Comment: Whoa there buddy calm yourself. No need to be a keyboard warrior

Comment: Also read the whole post before judging and making yourself look like a... yeah fill in the blanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Automagic updates (installs) can be made, but depend upon a number of factors

1) Your level of access
2) Desired level of control over version management
3) Access to network storage resources

If you could explain your environment a bit (better), we might be better able to assist in your endeavors.

I do this sort of thing all the time, but using enterprise tools such as Group Policy, SCCM, etc.

Answer these:

What is the command string to silently UNINSTALL any given version of Chrome?

What is the command string to silently INSTALL any given version of Chrome?

Do you have an .msi installer to use for group policy or SCCM-initiated installs?

Do you have an enterprise configuration management service available for use?

Do you have a domain environment?  Access to group policy?

Point being, what have you done to get where you want to be?